# failed to install QT 5.5.0

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

i tried offline install. i downloded the binary package from this link for Windows 7 64 bit : http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2 .

When i run the .exe, it shows an error in a pop-up " qt.5.5.0 stopped working ".

What could be the problem ?

I want to use qt designer to create some tools. i'm using python to handle the logic part.

I researched for sometime here. They were mentioning about Visual Studio. Do i need to install visual studio first ?

i've installed python (3.xx) in my machine.

Comment: "Do i need to install visual studio first ?" That depends -- there's several different packages (on the page you linked to.)  You need to install the compiler associated with that package prior to installing Qt.

Comment: i'm not able to install VS also. i'm getting same kind of error for this also.

Answer (score 0):

With the online installer, you can install QtCreator and code in C++/Python.
You don't need Visual Studio (unless you want to), online installer will bring mingw compiler.

Comment: i tried first online installer but when i run that, it wont install. Error will be something like " while fetching from repository: connection timed out "

Comment: Perhaps you are using a proxy ?

Comment: i'm not using any proxy. It is unchecked.